# Android KSoap Strong Type

Tags: android, listview, asmx

I am trying to bind ListView to an ASMX web service, however, I believe I'm not laying out the columns right:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ListView lstView = getListView();

    lstView.setChoiceMode(2);   //CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE
    lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    User[] u = GetUsers();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<User>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, u));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My GetUsers() method is returning the following:

```
User.Name = "joe";
User.Age = 30;
User.Name = "joe";
User.Age = 35;
```

The data is coming back fine, however, how do I tell the ListView which columns to bind?

Comment: Do you wanna show only 1 column per row or all?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display more than 1 column, you should either switch to `SimpleAdapter` or implement custom `ListAdapter` based on `BaseAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter`. I'd extend `ArrayAdapter` and override `getView` there. Here's the [official samples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) showing how to implement custom adapter.

But if you need only 1 column, you could keep your existing adapter and override `toString()` method of your `User` class and return the field you wanna show in the list.